# Declare and use variables using my own class in Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Inside a view I'm trying to use variable **created from my own class**,

**My** `class` **code :**

```
public class STG_Route
{
    public const string INDEX = "STG";
    public const string ADD = "STG/Add";
    public const string SHOW = "STG/Show";
    public const string PROFILE = "STG/{CODE}";
}
```

**My view code :**

```
    @{ 
    MyNameSpace.BL.TXT_and_ROUTE.Route.STG_Route Route = new MyNameSpace.BL.TXT_and_ROUTE.Route.STG_Route();
}
```

```html
<td><a href="/Admin/@Route.INDEX"><button type="button" class="btn bg-blue btn-block btn-sm waves-effect">xxx</button></a></td>
```

But this gave me errors, please any help?

Comment: What errors did it give you? You need to include that information in the question, without us needing to prompt you to provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants by definition are not instance members.  Constants are accessed directly from the class.

Add a `using` statement to the top of the `View`.

```
@using MyNameSpace.BL.TXT_and_ROUTE.Route
```

Then access the constant directly from the **STG_Route** `class`.  I hope you don;t mind that I took the liberty of fixing the invalid HTML.

```
<a href="/Admin/@STG_Route.INDEX" class="btn bg-blue btn-block btn-sm waves-effect">xxx</a>
```